# Migration to angular 2 - ES6 or TypeScript?

Tags: oop, angular, typescript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

My company is thinking about upgrading from angular 1.5.x to angular 2. The codebase is written in ES5, so a move to either ES6 or TypeScript is also in discussion.

TypeScript adds some OOP features over basic JavaScript and as the current code is more of a functional programming approach rather than use of OOP style (classes etc), I am wondering what are other benefits of switch from JS to TS when migrating to angular 2?

How much OOP is there in angular 2?

Comment: Your question is like asking which IDE to use. ES6 or TS is a choice your team needs to make. Fact is that TS is a superset of ES5 with features of ES6. So everything you can do in ES6, you probably can do in TS, too - but not the other way round. Regarding OOP: components, directives and services are all classes now.

Comment: The de facto standard language for angular2 is TypeScript. The framework is written in TS, the documentation is by default in TypeScript, and the code is much more maintainable and easy to write in TS. Just use TypeScript, it's a no-brainer, really.

Comment: It isn't clear if you intend to use native ES6 or transpile it with Babel. In the last case you're not limited to ES6 and can use ES.next feature set (which is more or less the same as in TS, OOP-wise). A2 dependency injection was designed with TS in mind, it allows to skip `@Inject` decorator and `this.injectedService = injectedService` for the majority of cases, that's the main benefit of TS in the context of A2 development. For ES5/ES6 vs ES.next, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript isn't really about OOP. OOP is orthogonal to types (think Java vs. Smalltalk). Typescript is about static type verification: are you using a string where you think you're using an array? I actually fixed a bug in a co-worker's code along those lines just last Friday where he was using a `for` loop over the length of what he thought was an array (Array.prototype.forEach makes that an easy to find error).

Is static type-checking worth the effort of adding type annotations all over your codebase? That's a judgement call.

ES6/ESNext on the other hand just flat-out offers you better ways to write code. I don't see how anyone can make the argument that

```
function(arr) {
  var foo = arr[0];
  var bar = arr[1];
  return foo + bar;
}
```

is better than

```
([foo, bar]) => foo + bar
```

Same for lots of other features, if you write in a functional style your codebase (like mine) is probably littered with

```
Object.keys(someObj)
  .map(k => someObj[k])
  .filter...
```

Now you just have `Object.values`. Plus about a million other features.