# Making http calls with Angular 2 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am following [Angular's own main tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) on setting up a Javascript project. This works fine, but it stops after 'hello world' and continues with Typescript.

Most typescript examples can be translated back to javascript and still work, but now I am stuck at making HTTP calls.

In **index.html** I load all modules as separate script files:

```
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js"></script>
```

In **app.module.js** I load `ng.http.HttpModule` and according to most answers here on stackoverflow, I need to include `ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the bootstrap part:

```
(function(app) {

  app.AppModule =
    ng.core.NgModule({
      imports: [ ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.forms.FormsModule, ng.http.HttpModule ],
      declarations: [ app.AppComponent, app.Actorlist ],
      bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent, [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS] ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

The HTTP_PROVIDERS part generates this error:

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' used in the bootstrap property of module 'class2'
```

If I leave that out I don't get an error, but I still can't call http from my **component**:

```
(function(app) {

  app.Actorlist =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'actor-list',
      templateUrl: './app/actorlist.component.html'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {
      },

      searchActor: function(){
        var result = this.getActor();
        console.log(result);
      },

      getActor: function(){
        return ng.http.get(this.url)              
                .map(function (response) {
                    return response.json().data;
                })
                .catch();
      }
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

This results in the error:

```
 Error in app/actorlist.component.html:2:0 caused by: ng.http.get is not a function
```

How do I get the http reference into my component?

Comment: I have to add, just using window.fetch instead of http.get (fetch is already supported in chrome and firefox) solves a whole big world of problems...

Comment: They are apples and oranges. `http` isn't glorified `fetch` and isn't available as global variable. You should use [dependency injection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501) to get `http` instance inside `Actorlist` class.

Comment: Why are you bootstrapping http providers?

Comment: I have no idea how to get the http functionality in my component, that's why I posted this question :) This seems to be a work in progress in the official docs :). I know fetch is different, but it seems to solve a complex problem in a simple way.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the constructor injection syntax in JS but after some searching, in your app constructor, try something like `constructor: [Http, function(http) { <...>}]` If that works I'll make an answer out of it.

And you're right, information is a little sparse for this in JS.