# Typescript/Javascript and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For the last months I have been studying HTML, CSS, Javascript and Node.js. I want to start with Angular now and I bought this course on Udemy (https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-angular-master-class/learn/v4/t/lecture/7251988?start=171) . In the second tutorial they mention that they will be working with Typescript instead of Javascript. I have no idea what Typescript is. Have I made a mistake buying this course and should I get another one? Or is typescript a vital part of Angular?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript that adds type annotations and static type checking. Angular is written in typescript so Typescript is a necessary part of writing Angular apps. However, many people (myself included) prefer writing in typescript anyway.

Comment: Come on guys, I'm just asking a question that I'm concerned about. Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation CRice. So it's a good idea to continue the course instead of looking for another one?

Comment: I assume people downvote this because this is something you can literally just google and find out what you want to know. If you want to learn Angular, than you have to learn typescript. If you want to learn AngularJS, on the other hand, than you wont learn typescript (Angular and AngularJS are completely different frameworks). Whether or not you should get another course rather than this one depends on what you want to learn.

Comment: TS is not necessary, and Angular app can be developed with JS (an example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501 ). But here are several good reasons why TS should be used, so it makes sense to stick to it.

Comment: Downvoted as this is something that you could have researched by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is very powerful thing. I am writing on typescript for half a year now and I can't image how would I build some big project on pure js without typings.

If you leaned javascript, switching to typescript wouldn't be much pain, as typescript in result compiles to pure javascript. And typescript has most of all new feature of javascript.

Go ahead, if you success in your course you will be able to build awesome things.

Comment: Ok great, I'll give it a shot. I'm very excited to start!

Comment: Don't mention downvotes, people use to forget how they started themselves and how support from the community is important.