# What does the following typescript code do?

Tags: angular, typescript

The following code is taken from angular source code, `di.ts`.

```
export interface AttributeDecorator { 
  (name: string): any;
  new (name: string): Attribute;
}
```

I understand this is an interface. But what `new (name: string): Attribute` is doing and why there is two types for name, `string and any`.

The above code is followed by

```
export interface Attribute { attributeName?: string; }
export const Attribute: AttributeDecorator = makeParamDecorator('Attribute', (attributeName?: string) => ({attributeName}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(name: string): any` indicates that a function that implements this interface is supposed to be called as regular function; it's called with `name` string argument and returns `any`.

`new (name: string): Attribute` indicates that a function that implements this interface is supposed to be used as a constructor, be called with `new` and return `Attribute` object.

This decorator interface describes the fact that Angular decorator function can be used as both `@Attribute(...)` [parameter decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) function and `new Attribute(...)` constructor, and they behave differently when being called like that.

`new Attribute(...)` can be used for annotations in ES5 and ES6, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501).

The function that is described by this interface and created by `makeParamDecorator` factory is supposed to work roughly like:

```
// decorator factory
const MyAttributeDecorator = function (attributeName?: string) {
  if (new.target)
    // Attribute object
    return { attributeName };
  else
    // parameter decorator
    return (target, prop, paramIndex) => { ... };
}
```

Comment: How it handle if they are using any instead of Attribute? like `new (name: string): any;`

Comment: @RameshRajendran `@Attribute` is [parameter decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators), it's used as `constructor(@Attribute(...) foo)`. I guess `any` refers to this statement, *The return value of the parameter decorator is ignored*. When being called with `new`, the decorator returns an instance of Attribute, as the interface says.