# Angular 5 : How to inject Router service with ES6/ES5 (without Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular5, ecmascript-5

**TL;DR**

I want to inject the Angular Router service into a component with ES6/ES5 (yes without Typescript :p).

---

Hello every body,

I recently created an Angular 5 proxy for javascript, because I don't want to use Typescript.

My library is available on github : https://github.com/kevinbalicot/angular-js-proxy.

It's works when you want to create your Component, your Injectable service and your NgModule.

Check out this example on jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kevinbalicot/nynzceb1/

```
// ng variable contains { compiler, common, core, router, platformBrowserDynamic, platformBrowser } from Angular 5 library

class Service {
    constructor() {}

    toUpperCase(string) {
        return String(string).toUpperCase();
    }
}

// Like @Injectable
Injectable({})(Service);

class HomeComponent {
    constructor(service) {
        this.message = service.toUpperCase('hello');
    }
}

// Like @Component
Component({
      selector: 'home-component',
      providers: [Service],
      template: `
            <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        `
})(HomeComponent);

class Module {
    constructor() {}
}

// Like @NgModule
NgModule({
      imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule],
      declarations: [HomeComponent],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})(Module);

ng.platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(Module);
```

You'll be able to create your Injectable Service and Inject it to your Component.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I want to inject an Angular service like Router for example, I get an Angular Injector error

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
```

Demo on jsFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/kevinbalicot/nynzceb1/4/

```
// ng variable contains { compiler, common, core, router, platformBrowserDynamic, platformBrowser } from Angular 5 library

class Service {
    constructor() {}

    toUpperCase(string) {
        return String(string).toUpperCase();
    }
}

// Like @Injectable
Injectable({})(Service);

class HomeComponent {
    constructor(service, router) {
        this.message = service.toUpperCase('hello');
    }
}

// Like @Component
Component({
      selector: 'home-component',
      providers: [Service, ng.router.Router],
      template: `
            <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        `
})(HomeComponent);

class Module {
    constructor() {}
}

// Like @NgModule
NgModule({
      imports: [
            ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule,
            ng.router.RouterModule
      ],
      declarations: [HomeComponent],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})(Module);

ng.platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(Module);
```

Do I have to inject an Angular service differently than a custom Injectable Service ? (My code here : https://github.com/kevinbalicot/angular-js-proxy/blob/master/src/index.js#L51).

```
function NgModule(metadata = {}) {
    return function decorator(target) {
        target.annotations = [new core.NgModule(metadata)];
        target.parameters = [];

        if (!!metadata.providers && Array.isArray(metadata.providers)) {
            metadata.providers.forEach(provider => {
                if (!provider.useValue && !provider.useClass) {
                    // Like Service class on example
                    target.parameters.push([new core.Inject(provider)]);
                } else {
                    // Like { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-EN' } provider
                    target.parameters.push([new core.Inject(provider.provide), provider.useValue || provider.useClass]);
                }
            });
        }

        return target;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading, any idea is welcome.

---

**EDIT**
My question it's not the same of [Angular 2 dependency injection in ES5 and ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859198/angular-2-dependency-injection-in-es5-and-es6)

Because, dependency injections are not the same between versions 4 and 5 (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

Comment: My question it's not the same of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859198/angular-2-dependency-injection-in-es5-and-es6

Because, dependency injections are not the same between versions 4 and 5 (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

Or please @estus give me an example with Angular Router server

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859198/angular-2-dependency-injection-in-es5-and-es6

Comment: It's exactly same. I posted an answer for clarity. Consider re-marking the question as a dupe if it helps, I'm unable to do this twice.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you don't need to specify Router in `providers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Injectable` is for TypeScript only, it uses emitted parameter types to annotate injectable class for DI.

Classes should be annotated with static `parameter` property in ES5 and ES6, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029435/3731501):

```
class HomeComponent {
    constructor(service, router) {
        this.message = service.toUpperCase('hello');
    }
}
HomeComponent.parameters = [
  [new ng.core.Inject(Service)],
  [new ng.core.Inject(ng.router.Route)]
];
```

A problem with this example is that `Router` should be global provider, it shouldn't be defined in component `providers`. Here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/nynzceb1/5/).

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular service like Router, it shouldn't be defined in component providers, because Route should be global provider.

Example here https://jsfiddle.net/kevinbalicot/nynzceb1/6/

```
// ng variable contains { compiler, common, core, router, platformBrowserDynamic, platformBrowser } from Angular 5 library

class DefaultComponent {
    constructor(route) {
        this.route = route;
    }
}

// You can override class parameters for inject Angular service
DefaultComponent.parameters = [[new ng.core.Inject(ng.router.ActivatedRoute)]];

// Like @Component
Component({
      template: `
            <h2>Route : {{ route }}</h2>
        `
})(DefaultComponent);
```

Thanks @estus