# InversifyJS for ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, inversifyjs

Are there any examples around using this ico with ES6 rather than Typescript for back-end Node/Express ?
I followed a few Typescript examples but nothing for ES6.
I've looked at the generated ES5 from Typescript but this seems a backwards step

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [covers this](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/basic_js_example.md) (also can be seen [here](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/javascript.md)):

```
var inversify = require("inversify");
require("reflect-metadata");

var TYPES = {
    Ninja: "Ninja",
    Katana: "Katana",
    Shuriken: "Shuriken"
};

class Katana {
    hit() {
        return "cut!";
    }
}

class Shuriken {
    throw() {
        return "hit!";
    }
}

class Ninja {
    constructor(katana, shuriken) {
        this._katana = katana;
        this._shuriken = shuriken;
    }
    fight() { return this._katana.hit(); };
    sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); };
}

// Declare as injectable and its dependencies
inversify.decorate(inversify.injectable(), Katana);
inversify.decorate(inversify.injectable(), Shuriken);
inversify.decorate(inversify.injectable(), Ninja);
inversify.decorate(inversify.inject(TYPES.Katana), Ninja, 0);
inversify.decorate(inversify.inject(TYPES.Shuriken), Ninja, 1);

// Declare bindings
var container = new inversify.Container();
container.bind(TYPES.Ninja).to(Ninja);
container.bind(TYPES.Katana).to(Katana);
container.bind(TYPES.Shuriken).to(Shuriken);

// Resolve dependencies
var ninja = container.get(TYPES.Ninja);
return ninja;
```

Comment: Yes, they don't have wiki where you expect to see it (in GH's Wiki section). Btw, if you're interested in Angular-like DI, it is [reasonably usable with Node](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38923612/3731501). It was recently extracted from `@angular/core` (which contains some non-DI junk) into a [separate package](https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js) by a member of Angular team.