# How to use angular DI separately

Tags: angular, angular2-di

[This article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) states that:

> The existing DI (angular1) has some
> problem though:
>
> Built into the framework - Angular 1’s DI is baked
> right into the framework. There’s no way for us to use it decoupled as
> a standalone system.

How can I use angular2 DI as a standalone system? It's not published as a separate package as I understand.

Comment: ah, thanks, it's there. I just never saw it mentioned separately anywhere. It's lacking documentation though

Comment: It's not an official package AFAIK - just community effort.

Comment: just checked it, it's empty :)... it contains `export * from '@angular/core/src/di'` in the `index.ts` source file. probably that's how it should be used. I'll try and post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was previously possible to import it from `@angular/core`. It is published as a separate package, [`injection-js`](https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js), by a member of Angular team.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38923612/3731501).

Comment: thanks, do you know if it's kept in sync with the one in `@angular/core`?

Comment: @Maximus Due to the fact that it is maintained by a member of Angular team (Minko Gechev), I personally count on this.